# how to load data from mysql using in between two dates

Tags: java, mysql

In the code below using java, I am trying to get data from mysql between two choosed dates and load it into table `jTable1` but the problem is when I run the data loads correctly but not until the second date.

For example, if first date is `2020-1-1` and second date is `2020-1-31` the data loads from the day of `1` to the day of `30` not until the day of `31`. The last day is missing! And if I choose dates from `2020-01-01` to `2020-02-01` it loads from `2020-01-01` to `2020-01-31`.

```java
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(jDateChooser5.getDate().getTime());
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp2 = new java.sql.Timestamp(jDateChooser6.getDate().getTime());

String sql2 = "SELECT sum(`msareffishmarket`.`Amount` )  FROM `manfz`.`msareffishmarket`  \n"
                                    + "Where `msareffishmarket`.`place` = 'محل الأسماك'  And ( `msareffishmarket`.`MsarefDate` between '" + timestamp + "' And '" + timestamp2 + "' ) "
                                    + " group by  DATE(`msareffishmarket`.`MsarefDate`)";

stm2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
rs2 = stm2.executeQuery(sql2);

//  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, rs.getDouble(4)); 
jTable3.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using your prepared statement incorrectly (though you are correct to think to use one).  Consider this version of your code:

```
String sql = "SELECT MsarefDate, SUM(Amount) AS total FROM manfz.msareffishmarket ";
sql += "WHERE place = 'محل الأسماك' AND MsarefDate BETWEEN ? AND ? GROUP BY MsarefDate";
stm2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stm2.setTimestamp(1, timestamp);
stm2.setTimestamp(2, timestamp2);
rs2 = stm2.executeQuery();  // do not pass the query string here
```

**Edit:**

Per the correct observations of @mangusta (see below), you should be using a date/timestamp range to search for your records.  Assuming you wanted all records from January 2020, you should be using:

```
WHERE MsarefDate >= '2020-01-01' AND MsarefDate < '2020-02-01'
```

Comment: he's not even using prepared statement, it's all in string. I think he should elaborate about `jDateChooser6`, most probably it does not return the value he expects

Comment: Not correct.  He is using a prepared statement, but he is just not binding any parameters.  My answer fixes it.

Comment: but there are no `?` variables to replace in his original query, you mean `prepareStatement()` produces an erroneous query even if there's nothing to replace?

Comment: You are assuming that intercolating a `java.sql.Timestamp` in a query string with single quotes around it would yield a valid date/timestamp literal, and this is not at all clear to me.  The best next step is to start with my answer, using a proper prepared statement.

Comment: you might be right, but he gets all dates except the last one, I don't think it has something to do with single quotes

Comment: @mangusta You're right :-) ... he shouldn't be using `BETWEEN`, he should be using a range, I will update my answer.

Comment: thanks all.  The answer is logical to me but it didnt solve the problem. i think the problem is with the timestamp used to get the two dates. now it gives me the data between the next day of the the date i choosed to the last day. and when i used the substring method to substring the date without time hour and seconds, it gave me the data from first date to the day before the last day!!

Comment: @MahmoudHassanMohamedHassan is this object `jDateChooser6` set up to the date only (hours=0, minutes=0, seconds=0 etc.) ? if so, after getting converted to the timestamp, it is going to precede `msareffishmarket.MsarefDate` timestamps for that date (all except hours:minutes:seconds=00:00:00) so it will not appear in the result

Comment: @mangusta if i choosed the first of jan 2020 then timestamp = 2020-01-01  14:16:13 etc

Comment: @mangusta now i used this way but still get the same problem :/

Comment: @mangusta      SimpleDateFormat dcn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date1 = dcn.format(jDateChooser5.getDate() );
        String date2 = dcn.format(jDateChooser6.getDate() );

Comment: @MahmoudHassanMohamedHassan what's the value of `timestamp2`?